# Extracting features from raster data using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, feature-extraction, flood

I want to extract flood related pixels from my imagery.

I calculated mLSWI(Modified Land Surface Water Index).

According to the literatures, mLSWI >= 0.5 is flood pixels.

How do I identify the flood pixels in my imagery?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

Comment: I am using ArcGIS 10.0.

Comment: As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to add additional details to it at any time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Reclassify (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//009z000000sr000000) or [Con (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000) to perform this type of image thresholding. In your case, it is common to assign pixel values of interest a value of 1 and everything else a value of 0. The parameters are pretty self explanatory for the Reclassify tool. Con, on the other hand, is a bit more cryptic. Here is an example of the type of syntax you would need for Con:

[image]

In other words, if the pixel value is >= 0.5, assign a value of 1, otherwise assign a value of 0.

Comment: This is what exactly I was trying to do. Thank You.